# Issue with sharp in host vars Ansible

Tags: ssh, authentication, remote, ansible

Since # is considered as a comment in /etc/ansible/hosts I'm unable to use a password containing a sharp.

```
[hosts]
host1 ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_ssh_pass=userpass ansible_su_pass=My#Password
```

Then with a raw command:

```
$ ansible host1 -m raw -a "whoami" --su
host1 | FAILED | rc=1 >>

su: Authentication failure
```

If I use a password without a # it works fine. Is there a workaround to this ?

Answer (score 1):

In the inventory file the example below give the desired result.

```
[hosts:vars]
ansible_su_pass=My#Password
```

But the variable is then related to all hosts in the hosts group so a better way is to create a file "/etc/ansible/host_vars/host1" and put the following inside :

```
ansible_su_pass: My#Password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#` inline, by escaping it with `\`, i.e `ansible_su_pass=My\#Password`.
Make sure you're using the latest Ansible as ini parser has evolved over time.